# Passing 'id' from one php page to another php page

Tags: php, mysql

I have two Mysql tables "addcoupons" with one column(couponvalue) and two rows with values 50 and 100. Another table "paytoget" with one column(usercouponinhand).
I been trying to get all the rows in table-1 to a html page and pass the particular id of the row when user click on its value to anther php page where it inserts it in table-2. But unfortunately i have missed something which causing it to print id of first row irrespective of which value user clicks.

My code goes as:
Page 1 (user interaction page)

```
<br>
    <?php                           
     $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM addcoupons WHERE customernumber = '$mobile' ";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {                               
    $index = 0; 
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $index++;                                  
?>
<form action='usercouponadd.php?id=<?php echo $row2['id'];?>' method="post" id="usercouponadd">
<div>
<h4 class="amount" form="usercouponadd"> <strong>Rs. <?php echo ($row2["couponvalue"]); ?></strong></h4>
<button class="addbutton" form="usercouponadd" type="submit"><span> <strong>Add</strong> </span></button>
</div>
<hr class="line" align="left">
<?php     }
} else {        
echo "None";
}   
?>                                 
</div>
```

The second php page (insert into table-2)

```
$mobile = $_SESSION['mobile'];
$date = date('M-d,Y H:i:s');
$date2 = date('M-d,Y');
$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM addcoupons WHERE id = " .$_GET["id"];
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
$index = 0;
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { 
$index++; 
$usercouponinhand = $row2["couponvalue"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO userpaytoget (usercouponinhand, mobile, date, date2)
VALUES ('$usercouponinhand', '$mobile', '$date', '$date2')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("coupon has been successfully added")';
echo '</script>';
}
else {
echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
} else {
 echo " ";
}
$conn->close();
```

Table-1 "addcoupons"
couponvalue
50
100

Table-2 "paytoget"
usercouponinhand
xx
xx

Any Help is Appreciated....

Comment: did you start the session?

Comment: yaa, i did...i just didn't mentioned it..

Answer (score 1):

I guess i figured out the answer for "my" problem. 
I just removed the form tag since i m not submitting any data from user, and added that addcoupon.php link to anchor link. it worked talking the particular id which user clicks..

Code goes like this::

```
<div>
                    <h4 class="amount" form="usercouponadd"> <strong>Rs. <?php echo ($row2["couponvalue"]); ?></strong></h4>
                    <a href="usercouponadd.php?id=<?php echo $row2['id'];?>" class="addbutton" >Add</a>
                </div>
```

Thanks to all who took their time to give this problem a glance...